# Deep AND Close array equality with Chai

Tags: javascript, testing, chai

So in Chai .deep.equals allows one to compare arrays by value and .closeTo (and .approximately) allows one to compare floats to a specified accuracy. I'm drawing a blank on how to get it to do both though i.e. test "close" equality of an array of floats e.g.

```
expect([0.1,0.2,0.34]).to.beDeeplyCloseTo([0.1,0.2,0.33333333]);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [mohayonao/chai-deep-closeto](https://github.com/mohayonao/chai-deep-closeto)

```
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiDeepCloseTo = require("chai-deep-closeto");

chai.use(chaiDeepCloseTo);

expect([ 1.00001, [ 2.00001, 3.00001 ], 4.00001 ])
    .to.be.deep.closeTo([ 1, [ 2, 3 ], 4 ], 1e-4);
```